# I can't send or receive emails (ZPanel, AWS, CloudFlare, SuperDominios)

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare

Can you help me with this problem? I can not send emails from my server, or configure. l'm using ZPanel on my VPS.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have the correct mail and mx records in your zone file. I would confirm with your mail provider what these should be, then configure them properly at your DNS provider.